# SpeechClient.dll in Visual Studio UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I can't add `SpeechClient.dll` in Visual Studio - Universal Windows Platform. On the other hand, `SpeechClient.dll` can add in WPF. There's a necessary reason that I have to work on UWP. I have been trying to solve this problem, but it doesn't work. What should I have to fix? Please, help me.

**Note:** `SpeechClient.dll` from Project Oxford

The error appears like this:

[image]

Comment: Please add some more information about what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I was trying to add reference of Speech API Project Oxford on UWP. Since it is .net framework and UWP is .net core, error appears like that. I am finding way to working on it. Still no any solutions. :'(

Answer (score 0):

UWP projects run on .NET Core. The DLL you try to reference requires the .NET Framework. These frameworks are incompatible. Try and find a version of the assembly that supports .NET Core.

More details here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/default.aspx

[image]